# How do I put a right accessory button onto the current location callout?

Tags: ios, gps, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I want to add a right accessory button to the current user location callout.  I've found a few questions on the topic but they don't seem to work for me.  Here is the code I have so far, I have successfully put the right accessory button onto my other annotations:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)_mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
        //TODO: this doesn't seem to be working?  
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) {
        MKAnnotationView * aV = [mapView viewForAnnotation:annotation];
        aV.canShowCallout = YES;
        aV.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        return nil;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

I've read in a few places that the solution is to make a custom MKAnnotationView for the User Location but I haven't seen a demonstration of how this is done for the user location -- I have successfully done this for the other annotations on my map.

Sample code would be the most helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Again you should get reference of user location annotation view. 
Following methods gets called in iOS >= 5

**Option 1**

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views {
    MKAnnotationView *aV; 
     for (aV in views) {
           if ([aV.annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) {
                MKAnnotationView* annotationView = aV;
                annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
            }
     }
}
```

See the delegate method below as well

**Alternative Method**

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
     MKAnnotationView* annotationView = [mapView viewForAnnotation:userLocation];   
     annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
}
```

Make sure to add the delegate method so you can do whatever when the callout button is tapped:

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
```

In any iOS either of these method gets called and you can add right/left accessorybutton to it. ensure that you do not add this button twice by checking subview count of user location annotation view.

You can also add/remove accessoryviews it in runtime, but I believe you will not want to remove it.buttons

Comment: Thanks @chatur, that did work!  Btw, how would you support both iOS 4.x and iOS 5 versions?

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is that you are returning nil in both cases. You should also use a reuse identifier.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)_mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
 {

 if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) {
    MKAnnotationView * aV = [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"locationView"];
    if (aV == nil) 
       aV = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"locationView"];
    aV.canShowCallout = YES;
    aV.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    return aV;
  }
return nil;
}
```

You will also need to implement:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)_mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
```

for the behavior of the callout accessory.

Comment: Looks very promising, I'll give it a try and vote accordingly!

Comment: Did this work for you? I have pretty much the same code in one of my apps and I have had no problems.

Comment: Afraid not!  I see no user location marker on the map now, something amiss.  If I change it back to return nil then it works as before but of course the accessory button doesn't show.  Suggestions?

Comment: This does not work because `MKAnnotationView` per se doesn't display anything. You need to either set the image property or use a subclass. The blue user location view is implemented by a private subclass called `MKModernUserLocationView` (in iOS 7). @chatur's answer is correct.